# Using HTML, how can I manipulate a user-uploaded file and then allow that user to download it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to have the user upload a .wav file, reverse the order of the samples so that the file sounds backwards, and allow the user to download the reversed file. I have written the reversing algorithm in Node.js, but now I'm thinking that it can't be done with Node - 'HTML runs on the browser, Node runs on the server'.

But it seems so simple - the reversed file is just a byte array. I want a 'download reversed .wav' button - how is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you're written this code in javascript and it works within nodejs, you might consider adapting it to run totally within the browser.  The user would never have to actually upload/download the file, they would select the file in their browser, your code would run in the context of the web page, and then present them with the result to "download", without ever sending any data to the server.

Comment: @Grax32 what do you mean 'download' the result? You say that they never have to actually upload or download, but then say 'download' - I don't understand. Can you give me a brief idea of how I might go about this?